# Is there a way to search a python dictionary using a wild character in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python dictionary file that is returned from an api call. The spelling of the keys in the dictionary varies and there is no way of knowing in advance what that spelling is. For example any of the three dictionaries below can be returned from the api call.

dict = {
'dogs': 'some string',
'cats': 'some string'
}

dict = {
'wild dogs':'some string',
'Cats' :'some string'
}

dict = {
'DOGS':'some string',
'Cat': 'some string'
}

If lets say I want to pull the value value of the dog key from the dictionary without knowing which dictionary the api will return. how can I do that? Can I search using a wild character ? 
Right now Im using a bunch of if statements like so:

```
for dict_key in dict:
  if dict_key == 'dogs':
    value = dict['dogs']
    return value
  elif dict_key == 'wild dogs':
    value = dict['wild dogs']
    return value
  elif dict_key == 'DOGS':
    value = dict['DOGS']
    return value
```

but that is not very efficient as there are many possible permutations for "dog"  and it is not very time efficient to execute. Im wondering if I can do something like this instead

```
for dict_key in dict:
 if dict_key contains the letters 'd', 'o' and 'g' regardless of capitalization:
   get the correct_key
   return dict[correct_key]
```

or something along those lines. Is this possible at all in python?

Thanks

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have free access to the keys of `myDict` (as I'd strongly advise not to use a [built-in name](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-dict) for your variables) through `myDict.keys()`.

That means you can do something like this:

```
>>> myDict = { 'DOGS':'some string', 'Cat': 'some string' }
>>> [key for key in myDict.keys() if 'dogs' in key.lower()]
['DOGS']
```

-- note that this necessarily returns a *list*, because the looser your testing, the greater the chance that more than one key will match. This one-line form of processing a list is known as a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**. Essentially, it creates a new list by processing all elements of an input list – in this case, the list of dictionary keys.

To test your 'all of the letters of `dog` anywhere in the key name', use something like this:

```
>>> [key for key in myDict.keys() if all(char in key.lower() for char in 'dog')]
['DOGS']
>>> [key for key in myDict.keys() if all(char in key.lower() for char in 'act')]
['Cat']
```

For list comprehensions, the default when accessing a dictionary is to go through its `keys`, so you actually can leave that out:

```
>>> myDict = { 'wild dogs':'some string', 'Cats' :'some string' }
>>> [key for key in myDict if all(char in key.lower() for char in 'dog')]
['wild dogs']
```

And to immediately retrieve the associated key value, just add its dictionary name:

```
>>> [myDict[key] for key in myDict.keys() if all(char in key.lower() for char in 'dog')]
['some string']
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much. This is very helpful. Im new to python and still learning. How can I learn more about the format of scripting that you used. You have everything in one line which looks very elegant as opposed to writing a bunch of nested if and for statements. Thanks again.